# How to export HTML Output using downloadHandler in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app using the compare_df function as part of the compareDF package and it produces an HTML output. I was wondering how to export this as an HTML file using downloadHandler? This is my attempt:

Partial Code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
sliderPanel(
   downloadButton("Export_HTML", "Export as Data Listing")
  ),
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(uiOutput('html'))
  )

server <- function(input,output){

a<-- c("1","2","3")

diff<-compare_df(filedata2, filedata1, group_col = a)
   output$html <- renderUI({

      HTML(knit2html(text=diff[["html_output"]], fragment.only=TRUE))
})

  output$Export_HTML <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Comparison-", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {

      saveWidget(as_widget(diff[["html_output"]]), file, selfcontained = TRUE)
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download html file when comparing two datasets, we need to have two files in  application structure

1. app.R
2. report.Rmd

app.R

```
library(shiny) 
library(diffobj)
library(rmarkdown)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton('downloadReport')
  ),
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(htmlOutput('html'))
)

server <- function(input,output){
  
  filedata1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b= c(3,5,8,9))
  filedata2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b= c(4,5,8,10))
  

  
  output$html <- renderUI({
    
    
    HTML(as.character(diffPrint(filedata2, filedata1, color.mode="rgb", format="html",
                                style=list(html.output="diff.w.style"))))
  })
  
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('Compare-report', "html", sep = '.')
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
      
      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
      
      out <- render('report.Rmd')
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

report.Rmd

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}


filedata1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b= c(3,5,8,9))
filedata2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b= c(4,5,8,10))

HTML(as.character(as.character(diffPrint(filedata2, filedata1, color.mode="rgb", format="html",
                                 style=list(html.output="diff.w.style")))))


```
````

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the Shiny Tutorial page on using the download handler to produce HTML through an R Markdown template: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html